# sorting of events based on date and time in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, datetime

What if not only dates I need to compare time along with date. Ex: today I have 3 events:

1. first priority is to get the gradeReleased=0 events (internally they should be sort on close date and time)
2. second priority is to get the events which are started but not closed
3. third priority is to get the events which are not started and not closed (if there are more than one event then should be sorted based on start date and time)
4. fourth is to get the completed events ( if there are more than 1 completed then they should be sorted based on close date and time)
   I need this order, will it possible only with CURDATE() or should I use NOW() in mysql?

table data is like below

| assId | title | fromDate | toDate | isActive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | e1 | 2021-01-12 9:00:00 | 2021-01-12 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | e2 | 2021-01-12 8:00:00 | 2021-01-12 9:30:00 | 1 |
| 3 | e3 | 2021-01-12 6:00:00 | 2021-01-12 7:30:00 | 1 |
| 4 | e4 | 2021-01-12 5:00:00 | 2021-01-12 8:00:00 | 1 |
| 5 | e5 | 2021-01-12 9:00:00 | 2021-01-13 12:00:00 | 1 |
| 6 | e6 | 2021-01-13 9:30:00 | 2021-01-13 19:30:00 | 1 |

After sorting it should be  if the current time is 2022-01-12 9:01:00

| assId | title | fromDate | toDate | isActive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | e2 | 2021-01-12 8:00:00 | 2021-01-12 9:30:00 | 1 |
| 2 | e1 | 2021-01-12 9:00:00 | 2021-01-12 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 3 | e5 | 2021-01-12 9:00:00 | 2021-01-13 12:00:00 | 1 |
| 4 | e6 | 2021-01-13 9:30:00 | 2021-01-13 19:30:00 | 1 |
| 5 | e4 | 2021-01-12 5:00:00 | 2021-01-12 8:00:00 | 1 |
| 6 | e3 | 2021-01-12 6:00:00 | 2021-01-12 7:30:00 | 1 |

Current query:

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM 
  events AS ass 
WHERE 
  isActive = 1 
  AND ass.fromDate <= '2022-01-12' AND ass.toDate >= '2022-01-13'
ORDER BY
  (
    CASE
      WHEN ass.closeDate > CURDATE()  AND ass.openDate < CURDATE() AND ass.isDraft=0 THEN 2
      WHEN ass.closeDate > CURDATE() AND ass.openDate > CURDATE() AND ass.isDraft=0 THEN 1
      WHEN ass.closeDate < CURDATE() AND ass.openDate < CURDATE() AND ass.isDraft=0  THEN 0
    END
  ) DESC, 
  (
    CASE 
      WHEN ass.closeDate < CURDATE() AND ass.openDate < CURDATE() AND ass.isDraft=0 THEN ass.closeDate
      ELSE ass.openDate 
    END
  ) ASC
);
```

Comment: Anything not working with `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Kindly add the query you tried and also desired output that you want.

Comment: Add proper sample data, your current query, and desired output. Hopefully you are not storing the data literally in the format you've shown here. You need separate `start` and `end` columns in the table, both using the `datetime` type. Then you can easily `ORDER BY start`. P.S. It's not clear how ordering the list items by their date and time has anything to do with comparing to the current time? You seem to have slightly conflated two things there...please clarify.

Comment: yes. I am trying to sort the events based on start date and time and end date and time using ORDER BY. I have used CURDATE() to compare and NOW() also tried so which one will give correct results?

Comment: CURDATE() will only compare DATES but my requirement is to compare TIME also. suppose on same day(13/01/2022) if I have 4 events then need to sort them based on close time

Comment: Sorting isn't the same as comparing, as I pointed out above. Curdate() and now() can't be useful for sorting. Order by will give you reliable results, but only if your data is stored in a sebsible format as I described above. Please edit your question with all the information as I requested, instead of posting comments which mostly just repeat what you already said at the beginning.

Comment: @ADyson  I have edited my question. please help me

Comment: As I requested, as well as the code please also provide proper examples of the rows of data from your table, and and example of result you want to get from the query, based on that table data. Also, the query is incomplete, please please the full query you're using, not just the ORDER BY clause. In short, we need a [mre] of your issue.

Comment: now I have added data as well.

Comment: Thanks. Are `fromDate` and `toDate` set as `DATETIME` columns in the table?

Comment: Also please define "started", "closed" and "completed". e.g. I guess "started" means the fromDate is less than the current time, and maybe "closed" means the toDate is after the current time? is "completed" different to "closed", or not?

Comment: But broadly yes to do the kind of comparisons you're doing in your CASE statements and get them to take into account the date, you'd need to compare the values against NOW() - it's easy to understand that just by reading the mysql manual, it explains already that CURDATE only outputs the date (with no time component) and NOW outputs the date and time.

Comment: @ADyson, The fromDate and toDate set as DATETIME